# How could I receive a Parcel from Germany at Lithuanian Parcel Station?

Tags: germany, shipping, lithuania

I need to receive a parcel from Germany. I am in Lithuania and have no locker in a parcel station yet. The parcel is not sent yet.

I know parcels sent via "Deutsche Post" will be delivered by "itella" in Lithuania. But I could not find information about delivery by "itella" to parcel stations. My favorite parcel stations would be "omniva" or "dpd". But others would work too.

The question: How could I receive a German parcel at a parcel station in Lithuania and what does the sender need to write on the package or its label?

Some more background: parcel stations do not interact with all delivery companies and the delivering companies do not deliver to all parcel stations. So one needs to know which combinations of delivering companies (DHL, itella) and parcel stations (???) are allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - DHL (Deutsche Post) will courier packages from Germany to any address in Lithuania. What is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: The OP explains why in an earlier question which garnered no answers: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19512/how-to-use-a-parcel-station-in-lithuania-to-recieve-parcel-from-germany

Comment: I want to use a parcel station in lithuania. The stations in general do not accept all delivering companies. For example in Germany you could not send a parcel via "Hermes" to a parcel station of "Deutsche Post" / "DHL". It will not be delivered.

Answer (score 5):

After more than one year of experience now...

Deutsche Post is the only (casual) service which delivers to Lithuania, and all their parcels will be delivered by their partner itella. Itella now have parcel stations, but one can not give the address of a station as delivery-address. They try to bring the parcel to the home, and if there is nobody they will place it into such a station. Then they will send a message and a code to a phone number they associate with the home-address.

Sounds good, but in real life this means: if you have an address unusual or hard to find, you will never get your parcels to your home. Second, it is needed you write your phone number onto every parcel. This is hard, if you get a parcel from your beloved grandma, who forget to add the phone number, or if there is no option to add one if you order things.

Next problem is that it seems to cause problems, if a non-Lithuanian phone number would be used. Sometimes you get the message "Parcel arrived" only and need to call to get the code to open the station. Other times you get a code and do not know at which station the parcel waits. More than 25% of times I got nothing. IF I knew, there will be a parcel, I called itella and asked for it (problem, if you have no parcel ID...) and recently (last month) we got two messages, that our parcels came back from Lithuania to the sender...

My solution now: I (ab)use an address in Germany to collect orders or parcels for Christmas/birthdays and so on. Then my family put all in a big cardboard box and I book DHL or DPD to get it from this address and bring it to my address in Lithuania. They need 1 to 2 days to deliver.

Sadly this do not solve all problems, so I would be happy for any advice others could give :)

Answer (score 1):

The owner of a parcel station will know what delivery company can use that specific station.

Identify the parcel station(s) you would like to use (they will have names or ID numbers), then email the owners of the parcel station(s) and ask how to ship from Germany to their parcel station. The owner should be able to advise you what shippers use their parcel station.

Comment: I wrote to itella "Do you deliver to any parcel stations?" They answered  "we Do not have this service". I am not sure if they already understand my question...

Comment: Write to the firm that owns the parcel station, not a delivery firm. Itella is a delivery firm.

Comment: Omniva does not answer since one week, maybe I have to ask again.

Comment: Write again, and also try "dpd" as well as the owners of other parcel stations you could use.